# How to make elements slide in one by one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, each

I am trying to make elements (divs) slide in one by one. But all I get is all the elements sliding in the same time. And I honestly can't figure out why. To my everything looks correct. Can anyone help me?

Html:

```
<div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:red;
   margin:20px 20px 20px 500px;       
      }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('.box').css('margin-left', -200)
                $('.box').each(function() {
                $(this).delay(5000).animate({
                    'marginLeft' : "+=700px"
                }, 2000);
                });
            });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/87yjhybd/

Any help is greatly appriciated! / Best Regards Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.box').css('margin-left', -200)
     $('.box').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(5000*i).animate({
            'marginLeft' : "+=700px"
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

**UPDATED**

I've missed $(document).ready(); :)

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ArtyukhAlex/ow9r8f7b/)

**UPDATED 2**

```
$('.box').each(function(index, element){...
```

`index`, in my code it was `i`, is an index of current element in cycle.
`element` - value. It is a DOM object of the element with index `index`

You can see it in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: You must be missing something, because I can't get that code to work?

Comment: Never mind, it was just me wo wrote wrong.. Yes this is exactly what I wanted. Could you explain to me what "i" does?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mycarousel li").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.box').stop(true,true).animate({ top : -45});
},function () {
    $(this).find('.box').stop(true,true).animate({ top : -5});
});
```

Comment: This looks like a uneccessery complicated solution?